# What is the meaning of (front-end nodes) in a cluster?

Tags: cluster-computing, frontend

What is the meaning of (front-end nodes) in a cluster? 
There's no wikipedia page for this term?

Answer (score 4):

It makes most sense to talk about a frontend if you set it in relation to a backend:

- **Frontend node**: accepts requests and routes them to a backend node.
- **Backend node**: performs the actual computation and records/relays the result.

Here is an [example topology](https://web.archive.org/web/20170928114727/https://www.bro.org/sphinx/cluster/index.html) in the realm of distributed network intrusion detection:
[image: NIDS cluster]
<sub>(source: [bro.org](https://www.bro.org/sphinx/_images/deployment.png))</sub>

The frontend splits up the traffic into flows and relays packets belonging to the same flow to the same backend (aka. worker). The backend nodes then do the actual expensive analysis on the network traffic, such as reassembling the TCP stream and parsing the application-layer protocol.

Answer (score 3):

They're the nodes that interface with the user/world, as opposed to **compute nodes** which are simply fed algorithms and data to process.